# Password protective shopping cart Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing a shopping cart website in WordPress. It should allow the user to see the shop, contact, about page only after login. 
The Homepage will consist slider images, and login or register button.
How to make it password protective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questions asking to recommend plugins are off topic, and you're not clearly asking for a plugin. But, a plugin is a good solution for restricting access to a site unless a user is logged in. Try https://wordpress.org/plugins/restricted-site-access/ or https://wordpress.org/plugins/absolute-privacy/ . Both haven't been updated in a while, but both work. You can set a page to be shown to those not logged in.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. https://wordpress.org/plugins/restricted-site-access/  plugin worked for the requirement.

Comment: I redirected it to my account page, login working fine. for registration I used  https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-simple-registration/ plugin, that is also working fine. The only problem is lost password option is not working. when I click on lost password option, it redirects back to my account page instead of lost password options.